# Oracle SQL Developer - How to create query that prompts user to enter two dates

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am doing a database course for school and we are using Oracle SQL Developer. One of the queries we are required to create includes the following

> Show X, Y, Z, values for all Master Avatars born between two dates (to be entered at runtime – the user should be prompted for dates)

I have successfully created the query to retrieve all of the data, minus the date input. I have been using `'Av_DOB=&Choose_Date'` to prompt the user for an input, and it works when I input a valid DOB from the table. But how do I go about making it so the user is prompted to enter two dates and the result will display any Avatars with a DOB between them? This is what I have, and I have tried various other ways but nothing has worked thus far.

First try -

```
WHERE Av_DOB BETWEEN &First + &Second;
```

Second try -

```
WHERE  Av_DOB=&First AND Av_DOB=&Second;
```

Can someone advise me what the correct way of writing the query is so that I get my desired result?

Comment: you probably need `Av_DOB between &first AND &second`

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks, it worked! Make it into an answer and i'll happily make you the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/BETWEEN-Condition.htm#SQLRF52164), you can write your condition this way:

```
Av_DOB BETWEEN &first AND &second
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE Av_DOB BETWEEN to_date(:First,'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date(:Second,'mm/dd/yyyy')`

- using the "between" statement and separating each value with the "and" clause.
- used a colon before each variable to prompt for input
- used to_date function to convert user's input.

Alternatively, you could write as

`WHERE to_date(:First,'mm/dd/yyyy')<= column
   AND to_date(:Second,'mm/dd/yyyy')>= column`

*in either case the first date must always be less than or equal to the second date.*